# What is the Common Lisp equivalent of the Scheme default-object?

Tags: scheme, common-lisp

I am converting some Scheme code to Common Lisp. I don't know Scheme. I know a bit of Common Lisp.

Here is the Scheme code:

```
(define (close-enuf? h1 h2 #!optional tolerance scale)
    (if (default-object? tolerance)
       ...))
```

I converted that Scheme code to this Common Lisp:

```
(defun close-enuf? (h1 h2 &optional tolerance scale)
    (if (xxx tolerance)
        ...))
```

Aside from `xxx`, does that look right?

Now, with regard to `xxx`, what is the Common Lisp equivalent for `default-object?`

I found this definition of `default-object?`:

```
The predicate default-object?, which is true only of default objects, can be used to determine which optional parameters were supplied, and which  were defaulted.
```

I'm not sure what that is saying. Is it saying that `default-object?` returns true if the argument's value is the default value (not a passed-in value)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the [Ordinary Lambda Lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/03_da.htm) section of the specification:

```
lambda-list::= 
  (var* 
     [&optional {var | (var [init-form [supplied-p-parameter]])}*] 
     [&rest var] 
     [&key {var | ({var | (keyword-name var)} [init-form [supplied-p-parameter]])}* [&allow-other-keys]] 
     [&aux {var | (var [init-form])}*])
```

The `&optional` arguments can be single symbols or a list with two or three elements.
In that case, the second value is the default value.
The third value names a variable which holds a boolean value: it is true if and only if the value bound to `var` was supplied by the caller.
Otherwise, a `NIL` indicates that the value is the default one.
For example:

```
(defun foo (&optional (x 1 xp))
  (list x xp))
```

With no argument supplied:

```
(foo)
=> (1 nil)
```

With an explicit argument:

```
(foo 2)
=> (2 T)
```

With an argument that is indistinguishable from the default value:

```
(foo 1)
=> (1 T)
```

In your case, that would be:

```
(defun close-enough-p (h1 h2 &optional (tolerance nil tolerance-p) scale)
    (if tolerance-p
      <supplied>
      <default>))
```

Note that the same goes for `&key` arguments.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much coredump.

Comment: @RogerCostello Thank you